# ORA - 01003 no statement parsed - Trying to select a distinct max record from a subquery that is currently returning more than one row

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, max, distinct

One of my subqueries is returning more than one row.  What I'm looking to do change it to return only one row, and of the rows returned to pick the one with the max value.

Currently, the subquery looks like this:

```
             (select case when floor(DATEDIFF(''d'', ProvNotify.start_dt, NVL(ProvNotify.complete_dt,sysdate))) = 0 then 1 else floor(DATEDIFF(''d'', ProvNotify.start_dt, NVL(ProvNotify.complete_dt,sysdate))) end
                FROM priv_wf_worklist ProvNotify
               WHERE ProvNotify.priv_application_id = pa.priv_application_id
                 AND ProvNotify.task_id = 600
                 AND ProvNotify.role_id = 100
                 AND ProvNotify.complete_dt IS NOT NULL) as "# Provider Notification Days",
```

I've tried changing it to:

```
  SELECT MAX(select case when floor(DATEDIFF(''d'', ProvNotify.start_dt, NVL(ProvNotify.complete_dt,sysdate))) = 0 then 1 else floor(DATEDIFF(''d'', ProvNotify.start_dt, NVL(ProvNotify.complete_dt,sysdate)))) end
                FROM priv_wf_worklist ProvNotify
               WHERE ProvNotify.priv_application_id = pa.priv_application_id
                 AND ProvNotify.task_id = 600
                 AND ProvNotify.role_id = 100
                 AND ProvNotify.complete_dt IS NOT NULL) as "# Provider Notification Days",
```

and

```
  SELECT DISTINCT MAX(select case when floor(DATEDIFF(''d'', ProvNotify.start_dt, NVL(ProvNotify.complete_dt,sysdate))) = 0 then 1 else floor(DATEDIFF(''d'', ProvNotify.start_dt, NVL(ProvNotify.complete_dt,sysdate)))) end
                FROM priv_wf_worklist ProvNotify
               WHERE ProvNotify.priv_application_id = pa.priv_application_id
                 AND ProvNotify.task_id = 600
                 AND ProvNotify.role_id = 100
                 AND ProvNotify.complete_dt IS NOT NULL) as "# Provider Notification Days",
```

It'll compile but then I get an oracle error.  Please help me!  Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is this the complete SQL statement? What is the trailing comma doing?

Comment: No it's not the complete SQL statement. It's one of the sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

The max() function needs to go around the value that you want to take the max of, in this situation it's your CASE statement.

```
 (select max(case when floor(DATEDIFF(''d'', ProvNotify.start_dt, NVL(ProvNotify.complete_dt,sysdate))) = 0 then 1 else floor(DATEDIFF(''d'', ProvNotify.start_dt, NVL(ProvNotify.complete_dt,sysdate))) end)
                FROM priv_wf_worklist ProvNotify
               WHERE ProvNotify.priv_application_id = pa.priv_application_id
                 AND ProvNotify.task_id = 600
                 AND ProvNotify.role_id = 100
                 AND ProvNotify.complete_dt IS NOT NULL) as "# Provider Notification Days",
```